# How to describe (enumerate) picklist enties valid for a specific record type in Salesforce?

Tags: reflection, salesforce

In apex code I want to enumerate the legal values for a picklist field. To do this I can just call `Account.Foobar__c.getDescribe().getPickListValues()` and I've got a list of Schema.PickListEntry values.

However it's possible to setup multiple record types for a given sObject. For example Account might have "Manufacturer", "Distributor" and "Retailer" record types. In the Salesforce setup it is possible edit (limit) the picklist entries for each field based on record type. So Retailer type accounts might only use a subset of the picklist values for the Foobar field.

So basically I want `Account.Foobar__c.getDescribe().getPickListValues('Retailer')` however this is not the syntax. The validFor method looks promising, but it seems like it is only for field dependent picklists - a picklist filtered only by record type returns false for `isDependentPicklist`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it in pure Apex AFAIK, unfortunately. The metadata API does expose it.

Related opinions: http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Apex-Code-Development/Any-way-to-obtain-picklist-values-by-record-type/td-p/287563

Comment: It's now possible in Apex to get the validFor. Don't know when it happens, but definitely possible since at least Spring 14

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old post, but maybe the info below will help someone who still needs the answer.

I found [here](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/NET-Development/Accessing-Selected-Picklist-Values-per-Record-Type-in-API/td-p/43405) that one can actually get a list of record type specific picklist values by making a describeLayout() call.

Using your example (C#):

```
DescribeLayoutResult result = binding.describeLayout("Account", new string[] { "01230000000xxXxXXX" } );
PicklistEntry[] values = result.recordTypeMappings[0].picklistsForRecordType[12345].picklistValues;
```

- Replace *"01230000000xxXxXXX"* with a RecordTypeId of your Retailer record type object. Use the query "SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE Name = 'Retailer'" to get the value.
- Replace *12345* with an index of your picklist object that you would like to get values of.

Comment: exactly what I needed!  Thanks.  Instead using the indexer [12345], which I found to not be consistent between calls, I used a LINQ expression to go by the picklist Name. Something like: picklistsForRecordType.SingleOrDefault(pl=>"Retailer".Equals(pl.picklistName).picklistValues